# SQL Server : How to improve a 3 join query using costly Non clustered Index Seek

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have a query which makes a inner join of 3 tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, <OTHER 'A' FIELDS> 
FROM C 
LEFT JOIN B ON C.Bin_ID = B.Bin_ID 
LEFT JOIN A ON B.App_ID = A.App_ID  
WHERE
   ((A.App_NAME LIKE '%%') AND (B.App_ID IS NOT NULL))  
ORDER BY 
    A.App_NAME ASC
```

Data present in the tables mentioned->

- Table A: 8000 rows
- Table B: 900000 rows
- Table C: 10,00,000 rows

Following is the stats revealed from the SQL Server query plan :

Here Two costly index seeks are used, the upper index seek has the following stats:

```
Object: B.App_ID [non clustered index, non unique] 
Seek Predicate: B.App_ID = A.App_ID[clustered index,unique]
```

the bottom index seek has the following stats:

```
Object: C.Bin_ID [non clustered index, non unique] 
See Predicate: C.Bin_ID = B.Bin_ID[clustered index,unique]
```

Now this query takes 5 minutes to execute on an average and I am not able to figure out what should be done make it faster since the query uses Index seeks already. {All joins are necessary for the result set}. Need Help !

Comment: OK, first of all: is `B.App_ID` indexed?? Are all the columns used as JOIN conditions (foreign key columns) indexed??  Secondly: `A.App_NAME LIKE '%%'` is a 100% **guarantee** that **no indexes** can be used - you cannot expect a search criteria **starting** with a `%` to be fast - never.

Comment: yes B.App_ID is indexed (non clustered, non covering) and all the columns used for join condition are foreign key columns. Does that mean for LIKE '%%' index will not be used in spite of the fact that query plan shows Index seek and no Index/Table scan anywhere in the plan ?

Comment: What about all the other foreign key columns?? (`Bin_ID` on B and C, `App_ID` on A and B)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only fetch columns from table A and you only check table B for existing rows.

I guess this would give you the same result and possibly a bit faster:

```
SELECT A.ID--, <OTHER 'A' FIELDS> 
FROM A
WHERE
   A.App_NAME LIKE '%%' AND 
   A.App_ID IN (SELECT B.App_ID
                FROM B
                  INNER JOIN C
                    ON B.Bin_ID = C.Bin_ID)
ORDER BY 
    A.App_NAME ASC
```

Comment: Hey the thing is that I must have this three way join in my query because I have a where clause fragment which can contain any table out of these three for the clause (this where clause fragment is passed to my query method )

Comment: @BhuvneshPratap You have a "three way join". Just add your where clause that filters on table B and C to the sub query.